# AR Camera with FPS Camera ( Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

i need help regard Vuforia AR Camera with Target Image.
I want to move my FPS Controller inside the Target Image, i have detected the marker and generated the Scene, but its like AR Camera does not allow my FPS Controller to move around or rotate !!!

Comment: Please explain a little more of what you want to achieve, what you've done and what you have tried to solve your problem so far.

Comment: Please see this pic [link](http://imgur.com/olpSzz5) This is my work. Everything is generated here on Marker Using AR Camera. My only problem here is that, Its not moving/rotation with these two joyTouchPads. These Touchpads are not working,  i cannot move my character inside the marker. I can shoot/kill but unable to move/rotate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. Since its a FPS, the GameObject will not be able to move forward without you getting closer to the marker. Without that happening this goes against the concepts of Augmented reality.

An alternative would be for you to make the scene move instead of the object. To explain:

`FPS.Move(right) -> Scene.Move(left)`

`FPS.Move(left) -> Scene.Move(right)`

`FPS.Move(up) -> Scene.Move(down)`

`FPS.Move(down) -> Scene.Move(up)`

> This is not the code, but merely for explanation purposes.

. This in turn would not need to have the marker move anywhere. Or need the camera to move closer, and giving an overall pleasant gaming experience.